# How do you use Sesse?

Tags: engines, websites

How can I set up a position on [Sesse?](http://analysis.sesse.net) I've been trying to find a way to set up a position on the blank chessboard for half an hour unsuccessfully. How do you do it?

Comment: Not sure if this was changed at some point but I'm pretty sure you can't use Sesse to analyze your own positions. It just gets run whenever Carlsen is playing some important event pretty sure.

Comment: Hi. If you want to set up a position somewhere, give this one a try. https://lichess.org/editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because there's a bug. If you open the console (F12 → Console) you'll see some errors. It seems that an essential file is missing from the server. Until it is fixed, you should probably use another analysis board.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sesse isn't meant to be used by random viewers like you and me. It's someone's private server with which he follows top level games sometimes (mostly Carlsen's). And if the analysis is on the web anyway, then why not share it with us.